# Variant of conjugate function: $V(s) = \underset{x}\max \{\langle s,x-x_0\rangle-\beta f(x)\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

Consider one variant of conjugate function:   $$V(s) = \underset{x}\max \{\langle s,x-x_0\rangle-\beta f(x)\}$$
You can think $s$ as a linear functional.

If I do the following steps:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
V(s) &= \underset{x}\max \{\langle s,x\rangle-\beta f(x)\}-sx_0 \\ &= \beta\underset{x}\max\{\langle \frac{1}{\beta}s,x\rangle-f(x)\}-sx_0 \\ &=\beta f^*(\frac{1}{\beta}s)-sx_0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Therefore I get the relation between $V(s)$ and $f^*(s)$.

I just want to check if my derivation is correct?

Comment: It seems correct to me following [convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate)